# A problem about the series $\sin(n^p)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-sums, divergent-series, trigonometric-sums

Prove that when $p>0,$ the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(n^p)$$
is divergent

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1558231/87355

Comment: What is $n$? And how does $i$ affect the expression?

Comment: $i\mapsto n$, most certainly a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: Thanks for correction!

Comment: The question has just been answered at MSE; see the link Carlo gave above. It's not doing too well here (2 downvotes, 1 close vote currently), but it looks reasonable to me.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, there are answers there but not fully satisfactory IMO.

Comment: @Jon: Not until a few minutes ago, but did you see the latest answer, by Sean Eberhard? This settles it, in my opinion.

Comment: Sean's argument is as follows: Let's say $1<p<2$. Then $(n+1)^p=n^p+pn^{p-1}+o(1)$, so if $n^p\to 0\bmod\pi$, then also $pn^{p-1}\to 0\bmod\pi$, which is impossible since this sequence goes to infinity, is increasing, and has small, non-summable increments $\simeq n^{p-2}$.

Comment: Thanks for all your discussion, now the problem has been completely solved in the link above(Sean settles it),I really appreciate for your help!

Comment: In case it's not obvious, I started here! I don't know if it's better to close this question or to post an answer with a signpost.

Comment: @SeanEberhard: My forensic skills were up to the task. Not too many people read 8 year old MSE questions for pleasure, without a prompt.